# How can I map an integer value to a string more easily in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I re-factor the following code to make it more concise and more maintainable?

```
if ($row['vocation'] == 1) $vocation = "sorcerer";
if ($row['vocation'] == 2) $vocation = "druid";
if ($row['vocation'] == 3) $vocation = "paladin";
if ($row['vocation'] == 4) $vocation = "knight";

if ($row['vocation'] == 5) $vocation = "master sorcerer";
if ($row['vocation'] == 6) $vocation = "elder druid";
if ($row['vocation'] == 7) $vocation = "royal paladin";
if ($row['vocation'] == 8) $vocation = "elite knight";
else $vocation = "none";
```

Answer (score 17):

I would recommend using an array, like this:

```
static $vocations = array(
  1 => 'sorceror',
  2 => 'druid',
  3 => 'paladin',
  4 => 'knight',
  5 => 'master sorceror',
  6 => 'elder druid',
  7 => 'royal paladin',
  8 => 'elite knight',
  );

$vocation = 
  isset($vocations[$row['vocation']]) ? $vocations[$row['vocation']] : 'none';
```

Comment: This, with the added comment that if these are coming from a database, you might be better storing it in a Vocations table and joining it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of used a switch to do this:

```
switch ($row['vocation']) {
    case 1:
        $vocation = "sorcerer";
        break;
    case 2: 
        $vocation = etc..
    default:
        $vocation = "none";
}
```

This is a common thing for many languages like C, Java, and C# and many others as well.

Comment: +1 for the example, but nothing that messes up the readability of the code is an improvement, unless the cases become signficantly more complicated than setting $vocation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion:

```
<?php

class Action
{
    const TYPE__ADD = 0;
    const TYPE__VIEW = 1;
    const TYPE__EDIT = 2;
    const TYPE__PATCH = 3;
    const TYPE__DELETE = 4;
    const TYPE__MAP = [
        self::TYPE__ADD => 'add',
        self::TYPE__VIEW => 'access',
        self::TYPE__EDIT => 'edit',
        self::TYPE__PATCH => 'patch',
        self::TYPE__DELETE => 'delete'
    ];

    protected $type;

    public function setType(int $type)
    {
        if (!isset(self::TYPE__MAP[$this->type])) throw new \Exception(sprintf('Invalid type. Possible options are: %s.', implode(',', self::TYPE__MAP)));

        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function getType(): int
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function getTypeStr(): string
    {
        return self::TYPE__MAP[$this->type];
    }
}

// Test
$action = new Action();
$action->setType(Action::TYPE__PATCH);
echo 'Action type is: '.$action->getTypeStr().', and its representative int value is: '.$action->getType();
```

Comment: good one! I guess it must be !isset(self::TYPE__MAP[$type]) in the setter.

Answer (score 1):

Following piece might be a little better. 8 elements are OK, but what if the list was containing 1000.

```
$list = array("sorcerer", "druid", ...);

$vocation = "none";

if($row['vocation'] <= count($list)){
    $vocation = $list[$row['vocation'] - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the suggestion with array and I'd use constants to represent the integer values like this:

```
define('VOCATION_SORCEROR', 1);
define('VOCATION_DRUID',    2);
define('VOCATION_PALADIN',  3);

$vocations = array(
  VOCATION_SORCEROR => 'sorceror',
  VOCATION_DRUID =>    'druid',
  VOCATION_PALADIN =>  'paladin'
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Start your project out right,  use const now to represent those numeric constants and save yourself some headaches down the line. (in addition to using switch/case as others have suggested)